# SSRS Need expression in tablix properties for each cell in the row. That will adjust the Size properties to reduce row to zero if there is no value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am getting an error on this expression. help? Visual Studio SSDT. I am putting the expression in the properties for the size.

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!BridgeBuilderApproach.Value) =0.2in,TRUE, 0.0in, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, the IIf expression should have 3 parameters:

```
=IIf([Condition], [True Result], [False Result])
```

Your example seems to have 4 parameters? The way you'd want to format it (without knowing exactly how your data looks) is likely the following:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!BridgeBuilderApproach.Value)=[Value that makes the row disappear], 0.0in, 0.2in)
```

Comment: Yes. and to add to this. click on Column Groups top, drop down to advanced then you see the Static 1:1 ratio where you can then enter the expression into the properties hidden. this will apply for the entire row and hid the row if 0 is result. =IIf(Sum(Fields!BridgeBuilderApproach.Value)=0, True, False)

Answer (score 0):

click on Column Groups top, drop down to advanced then you see the Static 1:1 ratio over in the row groups, click on the static row you need and it will highlight it on the design tab of the report, then go over to properties, where you can then enter the expression into the properties hidden. this will apply for the entire row and hide the row if 0 is result

=IIf(Sum(Fields!BridgeBuilderApproach.Value)=0, True, False)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the visible property of the textbox within the tablix.

Right click on the cell(textbox) of the table and choose TextBox Properties.
Select the Visibility Tab.
Select the radio button, "Show or hide based on an expression" and click the Fx.
Enter this or similar in the expression window based on your criteria.

=IIF(SUM(Fields!BridgeBuilderApproach.Value) = 0, TRUE, FALSE)

Brian